# Whose autograph is this on a Sailor Moon pencilboard?

Tags: sailor-moon

Whose autograph is this on this *Sailor Moon* merchandise (it looks like a *shitajiki* [pencilboard]) from the *SuperS* season? Is it a *seiyuu*, or a production company staff member such as an anime director, a *SeraMyu* musical actress, or is it supposed to be one of the characters' own signatures from an [*kigurumi*](http://www.usagi.org/doi/images/kigurumi/stars-nbashi/) live-action stage show? It looks to me like "Amさぎ" or "Smさき♡" but these combinations don't ring any bells...

[image]

(Here is a sample from a *kigurumi* show where the actress signed as Sailor Moon instead of her real/stage name in the same way that Disney costume characters at Disneyland sign as if they were the character)
[image]

Comment: I guess it's Usagi, where the A part is actually 月. I'm not sure where 野 would fit, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[nhahtdh's comment](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/24472/whose-autograph-is-this-on-a-sailor-moon-pencilboard#comment35353_24472) is correct.

> I guess it's Usagi, where the A part is actually 月.

A photo of a merchandise from Sailor Moon S shows that the first character looks like 月【つき】 (moon).

[image: merchandise from Sailor Moon S]

<sup>Image taken from [のり's yaplog, a Japanese blog](http://yaplog.jp/ladygoround/archive/316)</sup>

However, the signature seems to be a corrupted version of 月【つき】のうさぎ (Moon rabbit), as clearly shown in another photo of SuperS' merchandise.

[image: merchandise from Sailor Moon SuperS]

<sup>Image taken from [ゆかりん's Twitter](https://twitter.com/yk_89/status/762198048604729344)</sup>